# 502 Bad Gateway: nginx - Log: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading... [Django 2.1 | gunicorn 19.7.1 | Google Cloud Platform]

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I'm new in a company that have this project on Google Cloud PLatform, that I've never used. In my first day I've got this 502 Bad Gateway error. Lookin the log on the Google Cloud Platform I've got the following:

```
[error] 33#33: *285 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.217.172.212, server: , request: "POST /product/fast_appraisal/result/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.1:8080/product/fast_appraisal/result/", host: "avalieidjango.appspot.com", referrer: "https://avalieidjango.appspot.com/product/fast_appraisal/search/"
```

I've tried to edit the `app.yaml` adding `--timeout` and `--graceful-timeout` parameters to it like the following:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi --timeout=90 --graceful-timeout=10

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: avalieidjango:southamerica-east1:avaliei

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: manage.py
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
# [END runtime]
```

In the `settings.py` file `DEBUG` variable is setted to `False`

Looking for answers on the internet I found a few cases, but no one looks like mine exactly.

Locally I'm running the project on Windows 7, so the error only occurs when I deploy it to GCP. I'm new on GCP and gunicorn.

### Edit

After these days I've passed through a lot of forums, and added a few new configurations to my `app.yaml` trying to work with threads and workers to solve the question.

The entrypoint line looks like this:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --worker-class=gevent --worker-connections=1000 --workers=3 mysite.wsgi --timeout 90
```

This project consists in search a Postgres database on GCP gathering information about properties and running an AI to show some predictions about its values.

I've tried threads and process, but even with just my requests the application is too slow, even a simple page take some time to render.

Local tests run better, but in production it isn't working at all.

The AI wasn't developed for me and it uses a large joblib file.

The project doesn't use containers like Docker. Maybe it could help in some way if I "dockerize" the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stoped seeing this error changing `CONN_MAX_AGE` value to `None`, which keeps the database connetion time undefined. However this may cause some security issues that must be evaluated before deploy your application. If you change it, stay tuned on Google Cloud Logs looking for strange connection attempts.